# clear date from textview which was populated using android default date picker

Tags: android, datepicker, textview

my screen  has used a text view to display the date which was selected form android default date picker, now i want to clear text view data by providing clear button to date picker ..is it possible if please provide appropriate code and if not possible suggest me an alternative..Thanks in advance

Comment: post your sample code

Answer (score 0):

```
 clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             tv.setText(null);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         yourTextView.setText("yourDefaultText");
     }
});
```